# PayPal evTools Rest Api

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using the Dev Tools located at https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_creditcard?interactive=ON&env=sandbox

I login with my developer account and it sees my API Credntials and pulls the Client ID and Secret just fine. But when i try to run through the interactive demo i get an error everytime. Im not entering anything just using what the Dev Tools populates for demo purpose. Is anyone else having this issue or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It Turns out it was an overused test Credit Card Number. I sued this page to generate a new Test CC Number (Step 4 is all you need to do)

https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1413&viewlocale=en_US&direct=en